# Сложить графики с различным шагом

Tags: график

Есть несколько графиков построенных с различным шагом. Как сложить их в один, чтобы на выходе было 5 точек? Диапазоны у них пересекаются, но точки разные. Например 1 график точки: `[1:1, 2: 2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5],` 2й: `[0.5:2, 1.7:3, 2.9:5, 4.1:7]`.

Comment: во смотрите. я объединил - `[1:1, 2: 2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5,0.5:2, 1.7:3, 2.9:5, 4.1:7]`  :D в чем проблема то ваша заключается? о чем это вообще ?

Comment: нужно привести к одинаковому количеству точек(к 5)

Comment: Сформулируйте для себя сами сначала - как должно выполнятся это приведение? Интерполяцией, обрезкой, округлением, еще как-то.. Нарисуйте на бумажке желаемый результат, а потом, елси будут неясности - задавайте вопрос.

Comment: Аппроксимируйте точки, получите функцию, а далее просто.